# MySQL集計について、立てる列を横にしたいです

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL集計の質問です。

テーブル１：

```
ユーザー    商品     個数
Aさん      りんご    １
Aさん      バナナ    ４
Aさん      オレンジ  ２
```

結果：

```
ユーザー   商品   個数   商品   個数   商品     個数
Aさん     りんご   １    バナナ  ４   オレンジ  ２
```

テーブル１からどんなSQL文を実行したら上記ほしい結果ができますか。

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/33768

Answer (score 1):

`test` テーブルを以下の様に作成して、適当にデータを入れてみました。(ユーザー, 商品)カラムには `UNIQUE` 制約を設定していません。

```
> desc test;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ユーザー  　   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 商品          | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 個数          | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

> select * from test;
+-------------+--------------+--------+
| ユーザー      | 商品         | 個数   |
+-------------+--------------+--------+
| Aさん        | りんご        |      1 |
| Aさん        | バナナ        |      4 |
| Aさん        | オレンジ      |      2 |
| Aさん        | りんご        |     10 |
| Bさん        | りんご        |      5 |
| Cさん        | バナナ        |      3 |
| Cさん        | オレンジ      |      6 |
| Cさん        | バナナ        |      4 |
+--------------+--------------+--------+
```

サブクエリでユーザーごとの「商品 個数」を作成して、`GROUP_CONCAT` で連結します。

```
> SELECT ユーザー, GROUP_CONCAT(X SEPARATOR ' ') AS 商品リスト
FROM (
  SELECT ユーザー, CONCAT(商品, ' ', SUM(個数)) AS X
  FROM test GROUP BY ユーザー,商品
) AS list GROUP BY ユーザー;

+--------------+-----------------------------+
| ユーザー      | 商品リスト                    |
+--------------+-----------------------------+
| Aさん        | オレンジ 2 バナナ 4 りんご 11   |
| Bさん        | りんご 5                     |
| Cさん        | オレンジ 6 バナナ 7            |
+--------------+-----------------------------+
```